# Equations of state which are quadratic in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature

What are the implications of an equation of state of the following form

$P(V,T)=\alpha+\beta T+\gamma T^2$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ can be functions of $V$ and other constants characteristic of the system?

Both the ideal gas law and Van der Waals equation are only linear in $T$. Wikipedia has a fairly [extensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state) of different equations of state but none appear to have terms $\sim T^2$, which leads me to think these kinds of terms might be unphysical.

Any insight into what kinds of behaviour this type of equation of state would lead to, or links to work that studies such systems are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Offhand, I don't see any reason why an equation-of-state can't have terms that are quadratic in T. In fact, the Redlich-Kong, Dietrich, Ideal Bose equations-of-state at the link you provided are all non-linear in T, so if they were expanded out in a Taylor series about T=0 or any other temperature they would have terms quadratic in T as well as higher order terms in T.

Comment: Why should this be unphysical? At least in the sense of the first two terms of a Taylor expansion this is quite plausible. The typical equations of state that are cited are for *very* simple or grossly simplified systems (like ideal quantum gases or the van der Waals gas). And as pointed out by Samuel Weir even some of those are non-linear it $T$.

Comment: That's true. I suppose what I was looking for was an interpretation of a $T^2$ term along the same lines as the Van der Waals equation $P=\frac{T}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2}$, where the $T^0$ term has to do with the attraction between molecules, and the $T^1$ term has to do with the finite size of the molecules. Maybe such a thing isn't possible in general though.